# String formatting of column value React Table

Tags: reactjs

I am using react table V6. I have data which are shows in table as uppercase string. I want to do formation and display into capitalized format. Here is react table:

```
 <ReactTable 
 filterable
          data={items}
          columns={[{
              Header: "ID",
              accessor: "id",
            },{
              Header: "Sale Status",
              accessor: "sale_status",
              style :{
                'text-transform':'capitalized'
              }  
            },    
    ]} />
```

in Sales status data display as `DESIGN_CONFIRMATION` I want to display as `Design Confirmation`. Please give me suggesion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a utility function to convert the string in the format you want. And use that in the `Cell` property of column definition:

```js
{
  Header: "Sale Status",
  accessor: "sale_status",
  Cell: (row) => {
    const sale_status = row.original.sale_status
    if (!sale_status) return "";
    return sale_status.split("_").map(w => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substr(1).toLowerCase()).join(" ")
  }
}
```

```js
function toTitleCase(str, del = "_") {
  if (!str) return "";
  return str.split(del).map(w => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substr(1).toLowerCase()).join(" ")
}

console.log(toTitleCase("ABCD_EFGH"))
console.log(toTitleCase("abcd_efgh"))
```

Comment: Where I need to write function() ?

Comment: it retuns me 
[object object]

Comment: Still it shows [object object].
Is there any issue if I put in function like  `Cell: (  value :any) =>  toTitleCase(value)`


`function toTitleCase(str :any, del = "_") {
  if (!str) return "";
  return str.toString().split(del).map((w :any) => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substr(1).toLowerCase()).join(" ")
}`